# Remove "Sign Out" link in header panel but keep "Sign Out" link in dropdown

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

how do I remove the "Sign Out" link from the header panel but still keep the "Sign Out" link in the drop down menu (Which contain "My Account" and "My Wish List" links) next to it?

If I put this code in my theme's default.xml `<referenceBlock name="header.panel"> <referenceBlock name="authorization-link" remove="true"/> </referenceBlock>`, the "Sign Out" link in drop down is removed but the "Sign Out" link in the panel is not, which is the ***opposite*** of what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

Comment: Find any solution for this?

Comment: you got it working? I am facing same issue. Can you please help.

Answer (score 2):

**GO to Your theme directory...**

```
app/design/frontend/Yourtheme/Xyz/Magento_Customer/layout/default.xml
```

write below line...

```
<referenceBlock name="authorization-link-login" remove="true"/>
```

> php bin/magento cache:flush and check your frontend

Answer (score 1):

You could go to the file:

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/link/authorization.phtml
```

Copy it and overwrite it in your own theme and delete the li that contains the sign out link.

Answer (score 0):

In this file app/design/frontend/custom_vendor/theme_name/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml,
add this line,

`<move element="customer" destination="header.links" after="-"/>`

After that clear cache and check.